# Passing variable into Backbone.where

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, lodash

I want to form a collection from a JSON based on the obtained value and Backbone's `where` seemed like a perfect tool, but it looks like it doesn't accept variables. Is it possible to achieve this sort of functionality using some of Backbone, Lodash or Underscore methods?

```
### collection instantiated above

App.vent.on 'event', (obtained_value) ->
  desired_models = collection.where(attribute: obtained_value)
  console.log desired_models

### outputs empty array
>[]
```

It does work when I pass `key: value` directly, but I need to form collection dynamically. Maybe I've initially taken a false route and the solution is in the another direction?

Comment: That should work fine. What specifically is in `obtained_value` and what specific value in the collection are you expecting it to match? Is `obtained_value` a string but the `attribute` value a number?

Comment: @muistooshort, the idea is to render a number of models (`B), based on the  selected option (`A`) in another view. `A` is connected with `B` through `has_many` relation. In order to achieve this my plan was to grab the value of the selected option (id), and pass it via Event Aggregator on the controller, where I have access to `B` collection. JSON of `B` model hold relation to the id of `A` model `a: id`. So with the id of `A` I've planned to retrieve all related B models as a collection and pass it into its view. So `obtained value` is the number and `attribute is the string`, yes.

Comment: @muistooshort I hope that wasn't too muddled explanation. Thank you for your attention. –  curious_gudleif

Comment: Is `attribute` a variable or a property? Can you provide a runnable example (jsfiddle.net, jsbin.com, snippet in your question, ...) of your `collection.where` call? Are you really doing `collection.where(some_numeric_property: some_string_value)`?

Comment: @muistooshort It's vise versa: `string: id`. I've created [this js.fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M5J8Q/1967/), it not runnable but I hope it illustrates the process. Your patience and help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry but a pile of code in a fiddle that doesn't run isn't that useful, doubly so when your CoffeeScript indentation is all confused. All that matters is your `collection.where` call, the views and event bus are irrelevant. By the look of things you're trying to search for a numeric property using a string as I said, your `obtained_value` will be a string when `a_collection: obtained_value` fails but `a_collection: 1` works because `1` is a number so I'm calling this a duplicate.

Comment: @muistooshort Thanks a lot! I don't know how I haven't found that question, I've spend hours googling. `parseInt` worked like a charm. Cheers.

Comment: I found it because I was sure I'd answered this before and knew what to look for :)

Answer (score 0):

that wont work, you need to pass an object so it would be like this

```
collection.where({attribute: obtained_value});
```

in coffescript you can do the following

```
attribute_var=
     attribute:obtained_value

collection.where(attribute_var);
```

best regards

Comment: The question is in CoffeeScript, which allows the notation as written.

Comment: Well, wrapping in curly brackets did it for me, but as @PlatinumAzure noted, I thought I can omit them.

Comment: Unfortunately I hasted too much and didn't save the code. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Added coffescript equivelent. It has to work ;)

Comment: @Sudakatux, unfortunately id doesn't work. It's the same situation: when I pass a value directly in the `attribute:` it works as expected. But once I insert a variable it returns an empty array. Maybe there's something wrong with the data I'm sending? It's just an id.

Comment: are u sure about the type, menaning you are expecting a number and you are putting a string for if is an id you could try parseInt(obtained_value)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your goal is to vary the `attribute` you're searching for, since if the value is varied, object literals should work fine.

You can do it, just not with an object literal inline. Here's how I would do it in JavaScript:

```
App.vent.on('event', function (obtainedValue) {
    var finder = {};
    finder[attribute] = obtainedValue;
    desiredModels = collection.where(finder);
    console.log(desiredModels);
});
```

Comment: ,`finder[attribute]` returns `attribute is undefined`. It's just an attribute of the `desiredModel`, shouldn't it be inaccessible for me like this? Thank your for your attention.